# When Excel VBA reads data from a closed workbook without opening it, what is it doing exactly?

Tags: excel, vba, file-io, excel-2016

The following Excel VBA code reads data from a file without opening it:

```
Dim rgTarget As Range
Set rgTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3") 'where to put the copied data.
rgTarget.FormulaArray = "='C:\MyPath\[Closed File.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$3"
rgTarget.Formula = rgTarget.Value 'convert formulas to values.
```

Even if I put a very large amount of additional data in the file, so it takes 25 seconds to open via File > Open or Workbooks.Open, this code still runs almost instantaneously and gets the correct data.

A colleague of mine insists that if it is successfully reading data from the file, then *ipso facto* it must be opening the file. But obviously it's doing something different than Workbooks.Open.

It isn't about caching; even if I restart Windows, then start Excel and run that code before opening the large file, it still runs almost instantaneously and gets the correct data. And no matter how many times I open the large file via File > Open or Workbooks.Open, it takes 25 seconds each time.

Also FWIW, when I open the large file via Workbooks.Open or File > Open, Task Manager shows Excel's memory usage increases by about 154,000 KB, nearly quadrupling Excel's total memory usage. But running the above code shows only a tiny increase in Excel's memory usage, about 12 KB. The file uses about 29 KB on the hard drive (Excel files are compressed when stored).

Comment: It could be querying the file like a database using ACE driver. I don’t know for sure, but it’s a thought.

Comment: @Michael Z Thanks, but if memory serves Excel was doing this in early versions of Excel before Excel started including ODBC drivers in version 5.0 in 1994. But maybe it's doing what the ODBC driver does? Database files can of course be much larger than the amount of RAM on the computer; just need to be able to fit the indexes in memory.

Comment: Most recent excel file are actually a zip folder containing subfolders and XML files. (On a backed up excel, try adding .zip after the normal extention, and then poking around in the zip folder. Particularly in xl>worksheets.) Hence i speculate that getting cell values would only require being able to read into a zip, find the correct file and Parse the XML data.

Comment: @Stax, To test your idea, I tried converting the large file to the current binary format, .xlsb. That opens faster, but still takes 7 seconds rather than 25. And running the above code, after changing the reference to the new Closed File.xlsb file, is as fast as before -- virtually instantaneous. So, unless I've misunderstood something, I don't see that your idea answers the question.

Comment: What makes you think that it should work different than when the file is open after all is the same formula? Do the test with the file open and you'll see similar results, providing you can isolate calculations for the areas involved. Test 1 apply same formulas with both files open, Test 2 then close the source file and apply the formulas again. Remember to isolate the calculations in both tests.

Comment: @EEM, I'm not sure what your point is. Are you saying it should take 25 seconds (or 7 with an xlsb) if the large file is open when I run the code? I tried that just now and it was instantaneous, as I would have expected. It did not take the 25 or 7 seconds. I don't understand why you think that would take 25 or 7 seconds, unless maybe you think that time is spent calculating? The large file has no formulas, only text values. The 25 or 7 seconds is the time it takes to open the file.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to the action of opening the workbook, I'm referring to what's relevant: the time to retrieve the values from the workbook either open or closed, I believe that's what your question is about. Where did I said, "it should take 25 seconds (or 7 with an xlsb) if the large file is open when I run the code"?

Comment: @EEM, the time to retrieve the values, using the code above, from the workbook either open or closed, is near-instantaneous. What takes 25 (or 7 seconds) is opening Closed File.xlsx (or Closed File.xlsb), with File > Open or Workbooks.Open. Still not sure what your point is.